# Google Play Services were not found

Tags: android, google-play, manifest, ads

When trying to start my activity conatining an adView I receive following logcat exception:

```
02-26 16:02:29.766: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(26683): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

I created the AdView programmatically (without xml file) like that:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

private AdView adView;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("xxx");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_start);
    relativeLayout.addView(adView);
    AdRequest.Builder adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder();
    adRequest.addTestDevice("018eb6f8");
    adView.loadAd(adRequest.build());
}
}
```

That's how my activity containing the adview looks like.

my manifest file looks like that (removed other irrelevant activities):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>
```

as you can see I've imported the google-play-services-lib to eclipse:

[image]

and here you can see I've linked it up with my project:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using an emulator or actual device?

Comment: @dymmeh i am using my actual phone

Comment: hmmm and what google.com returns if you asked it?

Comment: What do you mean with "ask google" ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have to link Google Play Service Project to yours. You can do this by copying Google Play services project from:

...\android-sdk-folder\extras\google\google_play_services.

Import this project to Eclipse and them add it as a labrary in your project's build path.

Comment: I've already imported the google-play-services-lib to eclipse and added it to my app's build path...